# JS to toggle change in DIV's CSS not firing on first click

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Background** I have 3 ASP buttons and each one calls the same JavaScript with a parameter of a DIV ID.  When fired, the JS should toggle the display property of the DIV whose ID has been passed.

**Problem** When the button is clicked for the first time, nothing happens.  On the subsequent clicks everything seems fine: if the DIV is 'block' then set to 'none' and vice versa.

**Code** 
For buttons:

```
    <button id="pdp_section_a_button" Class="pdp_section_button" onclick="Show_Hide_Display('<%=pdp_section_a_div.ClientID%>');return false">Section A</button>
    <button id="pdp_section_b_button" Class="pdp_section_button" onclick="Show_Hide_Display('<%=pdp_section_b_div.ClientID%>');return false">Section B</button>
    <button id="pdp_section_c_button" Class="pdp_section_button" onclick="Show_Hide_Display('<%=pdp_section_c_div.ClientID%>');return false">Section C</button>
```

For JS function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Show_Hide_Display(divID) {

        alert(document.getElementById(divID).style.display); // on first click this is blank, on other clicks the DIV's current display property is shown

        var div = document.getElementById(divID);

        if (div.style.display == "" || div.style.display == "block") {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }

        return false;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `div.style` will read `inline` styles not all the css style properties bounded with element. Use `window.getComputedStyle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.style` only shows the inline styles, not the active css property.

In order to get the active css use the following.

```
var div = document.getElementById(divID);
var style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(div);
// equivalent to window.getComputedStyle

var display = style.getPropertyValue('display');
if (display == '' || display == 'block') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
} else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}
```